# How to pass variables through components Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have my `header component` that has a function to toggle a class on click, this works perfectly inside the header component, but I want to pass that behavior to my `nav component` that adds the classes according on this event.

**My question:**

How can I access these variables inside `nav component`?

**Desired behavior:**

What I want is to be able to add css clases when I click on toggleMenu

**Code:**

Header Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  private showOpened : boolean;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.showOpened = false;
  }


  toggleMenu() {
    this.showOpened = !this.showOpened;;
  }
}
```

Header HTML:

```
<div class="header-container">
  <header class="wrapper clearfix">
    <h1 class="logo">---</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-menu" id="menu-toogle">
    <label for="menu-toogle" class="menu-toogle" (click)="toggleMenu()"></label>
    <div class="bar" [class.animate]="showOpened"></div>
    <span class="icon-search"></span>
  </header> 
</div>
```

Nav Component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})

export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Nav HTML

```
<nav [class.open-menu]="showOpened"></nav>
```

Comment: Take a look at @Input: http://learnangular2.com/inputs/

Comment: Additionally, take care that you're using the correct selectors. I see that you use `nav` and `header` instead of `app-nav` and `app-header` - this will not work like you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :
Header HTML

```
<div class="header-container">
  <header class="wrapper clearfix">
    <h1 class="logo">---</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-menu" id="menu-toogle">
    <label for="menu-toogle" class="menu-toogle" (click)="toggleMenu()"></label>
    <div class="bar" [class.animate]="showOpened"></div>
    <span class="icon-search"></span>
  </header> 
  <app-nav [showOpened]="showOpened"></app-nav> <!-- put this code where you want to place your nav -->
</div>
```

Nav Component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})

export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() showOpened: boolean;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Nav HTML

```
<nav [class.open-menu]="showOpened"></nav> <!-- Now you can access showOpened value from parent header -->
```

You can find more information about components interaction in angular doc:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child

Comment: Thank you very much, after reading and reading I could finally understand how this work. Btw, just a final question, in case they are siblings I guess I should create a service?

Comment: I can be wrong but I think siblings components can't interact for now. If you create a service and provide it in AppModule, the two components will use a different instance of your service so you can't retrieve the same data. To make them use the same instance of the service, you must provide it only in parent component so children components automatically gain access to the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to implement component communication via a service because side menu and header or working area are independent or sibling components

Visit following angular 2 website and implement the service
   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html